# Magento 1.9 rwd submenu dropdown a little lower

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, submenu

I want to have [the submenu](http://webshop.dagelijksegedachte.net.testbyte.nl) `<ul class="level0"> ... Submenu items ... </ul>` a little bit lower. But when i hover the Main menu item, the submenu disappear? Try the link 'SPIRITUELE MUZIEK'

I tried:

.nav-primary li.level0 ul {top: 40px;}

How do i get the submenu 10px lower?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
.nav-primary li.level0 ul {
background: #f4f0de;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 40px;
z-index: 10;
width: 250px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
display: none;
}
```

That works for me perfect and it goes 10px more down.

Comment: yes i tried that also, but unfortunately you can't enter the submenu now...? Thanks in advance.